# while calling mstest from powershell, extra directory is being added in the relative paths in c#

Tags: c#, powershell, mstest, relative-path

I will try to make it clear

I have a MSTest Project called IntegrationTests

I have a PowerShell script inside IntegrationTests folder. This script runs the test using MSTest command line arguments.

The tests are being successfully called but after all the tests run there is a call to one method in my test method that creates report. When its trying to load the report.xslt file it is adding extra folder "TestResults"

```
Unexpected
................ 
System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Users\dev\Desktop\Test Runner\IntegrationTests\TestResults\Report Generator\Reports\report.xslt

Expected
................
C:\Users\dev\Desktop\Test Runner\IntegrationTests\Report Generator\Reports\report.xslt
```

why is this "TestResults" extra folder is added?

Just to make things clear this project is 100% working when i run this from visual studio.

If you would like to know how the relative path is being constructed in c# here is the code

```
 var directory = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase);
 var xslt = new XslCompiledTransform();
                xslt.Load(Path.Combine(directory, "..\\..\\Report Generator\\Reports\\report.xslt"));
```

I just want to know how can i get rid of "TestResults" so that my test can run normally. Any helps really appreciated.

Comment: What is the value of `directory`?

Comment: Do you get the same results running MSTest with the `/noresults` switch?

Comment: hi @AnsgarWiechers the value of directory is C:\Users\dev\Desktop\Test Runner\IntegrationTests\bin\debug\

Comment: hi @mousio it didn't matter